# Try на python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import sys

def throws():
    raise RuntimeError('this is the error message')

def main():
    try:
        throws()
        return 0
    except Exception, err:
        sys.stderr.write('ERROR: %s\n' % str(err))
        return 1
```

Выдает ошибку ситаксиса python3. 
Вообще при любом использовании try выдает ошибку.
Два вопроса , почему и что делать

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
except Exception as err:
```